# Populate ViewModel with data returned from Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the following view model

```
 public class VmPerson
 {
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public PersonAddress PersonAddress { get; set; }

    public PersonEmploymentHistory PersonEmploymentHistory { get; set; }
 }
```

I make a call to a function and pass in a `personId`, I then try to populate the `Person` class as follows and pass back the `ViewModel` (*there will be other queries in here to populate the address and employment history*)

```
public VmPerson LoadPersonById(int personId)
{
        var vmPerson = new VmPerson();

        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            var r = (from p in context.Person
                join a in context.PersonAddress on p.PersonId equals a.PersonId
                join e in context.PersonEmployment on p.PersonId equals e.PersonId
                where p.PersonId == personId
                select new
                {
                    vmPerson.Person.PersonFirstName = p.PersonFirstName,
                    vmPerson.Person.PersonSurname = p.PersonSurname,
                    vmPerson.Person.PersonEmail= p.PersonEmail,
                    vmPerson.Person.Age = p.Age
                });
        }

        return vmPerson;
}
```

But I get an error on all the statements inside select new{} which is

> Anonymous type projection initializer, should be simple name or member access expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public VmPerson LoadPersonById(int personId)
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {

            var r = (from p in context.Person
                join a in context.PersonAddress on p.PersonId equals a.PersonId
                join e in context.PersonEmployment on p.PersonId equals e.PersonId
                where p.PersonId == personId
                select new VmPerson
                {
                    Person = p,
                    PersonAddress = a,
                    PersonEmploymentHistory = e
                }).FirstOrDefault();

            return r;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, I have to wait a few minutes before accepting the answer. I'll be sure to mark it :)

Comment: Answers should include an explanation of the code and what it does.